# A textview has the same width setting in DP but appears different

Tags: java, android, layout, width

I set the widget width to same setting, i.e. 200dp but the width is different when appearing on screen? I would like to know why?

My UI consist of linearlayout (vertical) following by rows of linearlayout (horizontal). The linear horizontal layout has 2 textView each. One containing a label and the other a textbox.

The horizontal layout has setting match_parent.

I set the labels to 200dp each, and with different background color for easier viewing. You can see that the width is different.

[Red longer than green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqDup.png)

[width setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN982.png)

Comment: share your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue caused by the `layout_weight` attribute. I think you are setting it to 1 for the horizontal layouts and then setting it to 1 for label and the textbox. This makes it ignore the 200dp specification and hence its using the space required for the label strings ('Login', 'domain', 'Password').

To use a `layout_width` of 200dp for the label, remove the `layout_weight` attribute.

Alternatively, you can also set the text views to use a proportion of the screen (relative sizes) by using `layout_weight` properly.

Comment: To make it obvious to others, please accept this as an answer.